# pandas map returning all NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have two data frames `df` and `dfusers`

df:

```
ID   Count
A1   5
B1   12
C1   7
```

dfusers:

```
ID  FullName
A1  Mike Frost
B1  Jack James
C1  Mickey Rose
```

I would like

```
ID  Count FullName
A1   5    Mike Frost
B1   12   Jack James
C1   7    Mickey Rose
```

In my research, I ended up trying
`df['Fullname']=df['ID'].map(dfusers['FullName'])`

But the resulting dataframe returns `NaN` for all `IDs`. I was able to successfully create the desired dataframe using Excel Vlookup though. How come this is not working in pandas?

Comment: ...`.map(dfusers.set_index('ID')['FullName'])`. Map requires a dict or a series, I think you are passing a dataframe.

Comment: need to see data, but keep as concise as possible please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight correction, pass a series of `FullName` with `ID` as the index:

```
df['Fullname'] = df['ID'].map(dfusers.set_index('ID')['FullName'])
```

Or, with `replace` (also works with Series, though slower, as not vectorised):

```
df['Fullname'] = df['ID'].replace(dfusers.set_index('ID')['FullName'])
```

```
df

   ID  Count     Fullname
0  A1      5   Mike Frost
1  B1     12   Jack James
2  C1      7  Mickey Rose
```

---

Another option may make use of `pd.Series.searchsorted`:

```
df['FullName'] = dfusers.loc[df.index[df.ID.searchsorted(df.ID)], 'FullName']
df

   ID  Count     Fullname
0  A1      5   Mike Frost
1  B1     12   Jack James
2  C1      7  Mickey Rose
```

Assuming `df.ID` is already sorted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use merge to achieve this:

```
df = df.merge(dfusers, how='inner', on='ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, `set_index` and `map`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
dfusers['Count'] = dfusers.ID.map(df['Count'])
print(dfusers)
```

Output:

```
   ID     FullName  Count
0  A1   Mike Frost      5
1  B1   Jack James     12
2  C1  Mickey Rose      7
```

Comment: how could you do this if that ID column were instead a column with non-unique values in the database you merge to

Comment: @Skler... You would use merge instead of map which would yeild a one to many results... or you could aggregate the IDs to a uniqueness such as using the first occurrence of ID then still using map.  It depends on your expected output.